# Using data draw gantt chart monthly in android

Tags: android, charts

I want this type of **Gantt chart** in android:

[image]

For this which library is important. I will try `Achartengine` library but not getting proper result . So suggest me an example or library.

I want to draw a horizontal bar in the exact time when it happens"...the problem is that i can't(or i don't know how) draw an horizontal bar with not continous values (like a bar of a Gantt chart)

It's possible to create this chart with `Achartengine` or `Afreechart`?

Comment: have you found any solution on this?

Comment: i made this custom

Comment: Can you explain how did you make it @SachinSuthar

Comment: i made it custom using canvas.

Comment: but how did you make the proportions based on the month days? @SachinSuthar

Comment: here i draw based on two dates range .ex: if your start date 2/11/2015 and end date 2/11/2016 then display 12 month below so i divided in 12 month.

Comment: hello can you please get me the code for the same...